# Javascript: How do I do array methods on propertied variables i.e. var.hello.push? Too used to AS3

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, properties, typeerror

I've been trying to store data for multiple entities, so I thought a good way to organize it like I did in AS3 would be to store it under another variable, like

```
StoreInventories.Shellys
```

and then perform array methods on them as needed,

Eg:

```
StoreInventories.Shellys.push ("Stuff")
```

But this doesn't seem to work, something about

**TypeError: StoreInventories.Shellys.push is not a function**

that the console keeps spitting out. How am I supposed to get this functionality?

Sorry if I'm abusing terms - jargon isn't my strong suit and I haven't undergone any formal training.

Comment: Please, show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Method push() is defined for Array class. So you need to create an array first.

Here is the code:

```
var StoreInventories = {};
StoreInventories.Shellys = [];
StoreInventories.Shellys.push("Stuff");
```

Comment: Here's the fiddle I prepared so you can test it also : https://jsfiddle.net/j2katk4L/